# CouchbaseLibcouchbaseException, Failed to create libcouchbase instance

Tags: php, ubuntu, couchbase

Hello I was trying to upgrade php 5.3 to 5.4 on ubuntu 12.04 and I did I had some troubles to make couchbase & php work so I decided to remove 5.4 and reinstall 5.3. After doing that I tryed to make a simple couchbase connection but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CouchbaseLibcouchbaseException' with message 'Failed to create libcouchbase instance' in /var/www/taxi.localhost/couchbaseManager.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/taxi.localhost/couchbaseManager.php(8): Couchbase->__construct('127.0.0.1:8091', '', '', 'default') #1 /var/www/taxi.localhost/index.php(11): couchbaseManager->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/taxi.localhost/couchbaseManager.php on line 8
```

and here is the code form couchbaseManager.php:

```
<?php
class couchbaseManager{

    private $cb;

    public function __construct() {
        //include 'dbConnectionSettings.php';
        $this->cb = new Couchbase("127.0.0.1:8091", "", "", "default");
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        return $this->cb;
    }

    public function get($key) {
        return $this->cb->get($key);
    }

    public function set($key, $value) {
        $this->cb->set($key, $value);
    }
}
?>
```

I have done exactly what they say on the official website...

```
1) sudo wget -O/etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase-ubuntu1204.list

2) sudo apt-get update
3) sudo apt-get install libcouchbase2 libcouchbase-dev
```

and then:

```
4) sudo apt-get install php-pear
5) sudo apt-get install build-essential
6) sudo pecl install couchbase
7) extension=couchbase.so (in etc/php5/apache2/php.ini)
8) sudo service apache2 restart
```

Before I try to move to php 5.4 everything worked great but now I cant figure out what is the problem.

P.S. php info:

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul 15 2013 18:05:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that after installing couchbase libevent explicitly the problem didnt occur any more...